# Cordova/Ionic Framework work with ADAL

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, adal, adal.js

I'm new to Mobile development and struggling to auth working with Azure. I'm using Mac for my development effort. I've created Ionic project which is based in sidemenu template, added plugin "cordova-plugin-ms-adal" to it. Just to make sure code works, I added following few line to doLogin method. I get the error - "**VM370:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined(…)**"

Truly appreciate your help.

```
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);


    var AuthenticationContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcinc.onmicrosoft.com");
  };

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment yet - hence in an answer

I created an Ionic Tab sample app from scratch

Added cordova-plugin-ms-adal

Added a nav button to one of the views

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doLogin()">
        LOGIN
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Added doLogin method to controller of the view

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doLogin = function () {
        console.log('Doing login');
        var AuthenticationContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcinc.onmicrosoft.com");
    };
})
```

Do you have it the same way?